# Couldn't drop and recreate the table if exist on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Expecting to drop and re-create if the table is exist. Actual is instead of dropping the table, inserting data again on to the table.

```
BEGIN
PRINT N'Seeding [Proj].[UserTable]...';
SET NOCOUNT ON
--
-- BEGIN SEED DATA SECTION
--
IF OBJECT_ID('#tempdb..#SeedData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SeedData
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    CREATE TABLE #SeedData (
    [UserName] nvarchar(50) NULL,   
    [CreatedById] [bigint] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL  
    )
INSERT INTO #SeedData SELECT N'UserA',-1,getdate()
...
--
-- END SEED DATA SECTION
--
SET NOCOUNT OFF
INSERT INTO [Proj].[UserTable] (
[UserName],
[CreatedById], 
[CreatedDate]
 )
SELECT seed.[UserName]
,seed.[CreatedById] 
,seed.[CreatedDate]        
  FROM #SeedData seed
    DROP TABLE #SeedData

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

Tried codes:

```
 - IF OBJECT_ID('#SeedData', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #SeedData
 - IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SeedData', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SeedData
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SeedData') is not null
drop table #seeddata
```

I am not able to repro the issue,even passing the table parameter..

**Test :**

```
create table #test
(
id int 
)

select * from tempdb.sys.objects--you can see table 

if object_id('tempdb..#test','u') is not null
drop table #test

select * from tempdb.sys.objects--you can't see table
```

Comment: Your sample code is working. On my code, my expectation is to insert data only once. Lets say, For the first time, I created and inserted 5 data and if  I continue, its inserting again(10, 15,..). Instead of it, I want to drop the table and insert only 5 data to my table. No specific error.

Comment: `if I continue, its inserting again(10, 15,..)`..not sure why ..but you can drop and recreate at that moment of time again

Answer (score 2):

Remove the hash in front of '#temp db..'

```
BEGIN
PRINT N'Seeding [Proj].[UserTable]...';
SET NOCOUNT ON
--
-- BEGIN SEED DATA SECTION
--
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SeedData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SeedData
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    CREATE TABLE #SeedData (
    [UserName] nvarchar(50) NULL,   
    [CreatedById] [bigint] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL  
    )
INSERT INTO #SeedData SELECT N'UserA',-1,getdate()
...
--
-- END SEED DATA SECTION
--
SET NOCOUNT OFF
INSERT INTO [Proj].[UserTable] (
[UserName],
[CreatedById], 
[CreatedDate]
 )
SELECT seed.[UserName]
,seed.[CreatedById] 
,seed.[CreatedDate]        
  FROM #SeedData seed
    DROP TABLE #SeedData

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead for the drop table statement, replacing `[Database].[Schema].[TableName]` for the object you're trying to drop.

`IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Database].[Schema].[TableName]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [Database].[Schema].[TableName]
GO`